# Ionic ion-tab: How to open a modal instead of root page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I tried put a (click) event on the ion-tab element but nothing happens

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (click)="chat()" tabIcon="add-circle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use (ionSelect) instead of (click):

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="chat()" tabIcon="add-circle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And in the tabs code:

```
export class Tabs {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  chat() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ChatPage);
    modal.present();
  }
}
```